GridSearchCV and cross_val_score with KNeighborsClassifier using roc_auc metric is returning error because of decision_function
I am working on a binary classification problem.
The class distribution is Positive: 30% - Negative: 70%. Because of that, I decided to use as a metric roc_auc
I am then, running a hyperparameter tuning on KNeighborsClassifier but I have an error that I don't know how to solve
The version of scikit-learn I am using is '1.2.2'
Here is the code
param_grid = [    
    {
        'knn__n_neighbors': np.arange(2, 30, 1),
        'knn__weights' : ['uniform', 'distance'],
        'knn__algorithm' : ['auto', 'ball_tree', 'kd_tree'],
        'knn__leaf_size': np.arange(30, 1000, 20)
    }
]

knn = Pipeline([
    ("preprocessing", preprocessing),
    ("knn", KNeighborsClassifier())
])

grid_search = GridSearchCV(
    knn,
    param_grid,
    cv=cv,
    scoring="roc_auc",
    verbose=0
)
grid_search.fit(x_train, y_train)
grid_search.best_params_

The error is
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:778: UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 373, in _score
    y_pred = method_caller(clf, "decision_function", X)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 73, in _cached_call
    return getattr(estimator, method)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_available_if.py", line 32, in __get__
    if not self.check(obj):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 46, in check
    getattr(self._final_estimator, attr)
AttributeError: 'KNeighborsClassifier' object has no attribute 'decision_function'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

It's saying that the KNeighborsClassifier has no attribute decision_function
After some readings, I understood that The decision_function is used when the metric is roc_auc
Now, how to run a hyperparameter tuning even with this problem?
Also, even cross_val_score is returning nan when running it with KNeighborsClassifier and roc_auc as a metric
knn = Pipeline([
    ("preprocessing", preprocessing),
    ("knn", KNeighborsClassifier(
        algorithm='auto',
        leaf_size=30,
        metric='minkowski',
        n_neighbors=28,
        weights='uniform'
    ))
])
scores = cross_val_score(knn, x_train, y_train, cv=cv)
scores

The error is
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:794: UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 117, in __call__
    score = scorer(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 444, in _passthrough_scorer
    return estimator.score(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 722, in score
    return self.steps[-1][1].score(Xt, y, **score_params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 668, in score
    return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=sample_weight)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/_classification.py", line 234, in predict
    neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X, return_distance=False)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/_base.py", line 824, in kneighbors
    results = ArgKmin.compute(

Which is now du to predict()

Side note: roc_auc can be misleading with imbalanced data because it equally considers false positives, which are more common when negative instances dominate like in your case. In contrast, PR-AUC is more suitable for imbalanced data as it focuses specifically on the positive class, making it more relevant and informative when dealing with rare positive instances.
